# Can you solve this sortpher?

Tags: cipher, pattern, letters

(Sort-cipher, heh heh.)

This is a follow-up to ["Bees sting." = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 4]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111831/bees-sting-1-2-3-7-8-9-5-6-4/111832#111832)

If, indeed, "Bees sting." = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 4], then can you reverse-engineer this sentence?:

??? ??? ?? ??????? ??????? ?????? ????????? ???? ??, ????, ??? ???, ? ?????; ??????, ?? ?????? ????. =
[60, 30, 16, 77, 48, 49, 69, 17, 68, 32, 56, 33, 61, 18, 11, 62, 64, 19, 57, 12, 1, 72, 53, 20, 2, 38, 39, 73, 52, 21, 54, 63, 65, 55, 7, 22, 13, 50, 45, 40, 74, 42, 23, 41, 66, 37, 24, 3, 46, 14, 36, 34, 43, 35, 29, 67, 25, 58, 59, 4, 47, 75, 70, 5, 76, 71, 26, 10, 6, 8, 9, 27, 15, 31, 51, 44, 28]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence is:

> `THE ZOO WE VISITED TUESDAY REALLY PERTURBED ONLY ME, LUKE, AND JIM, I GUESS; ANYWAY, WE CABBED HOME`.

How I found it:

> Say you sort all the letters in order of the numbers. Obviously, they'll be something along the lines of "AAAABBCCCCCCDDEEEEEEE...". So if you start with a *blank* list of numbers, all you have to do is figure out where to place the 25 'dividers' separating different types of letters. (If a letter doesn't exist in the sentence, that just means two dividers will go in the same place.)
>
>  We can detect these 'dividers' by looking for numbers that appear *earlier* than the numbers before them. For example, here the number 60 appears earlier than 59. That means between 59 and 60 is one divider.
>
>  This strategy might not give us *all* the dividers - for instance, if all the Ss happen to come after all the Rs, then we'll miss the divider between R and S. But it does give us most of them, especially with long sentences. Here, the strategy gives us 22 dividers.
>
>  [image: image of line of letters "AAAAAABBBCC...", each with a number over them; 22 numbers are highlighted]
>
>  Then you can just assign slots to letters -- try to put common letters in big slots and uncommon letters in small ones. If things aren't lining up, either put an extra divider in the middle of a section, or put it with one you already have to skip a letter.
>
>
>  After that, looking at the actual words that you've made, it's easy to move any dividers to correct a few typos. (I had originally guessed everything except for one divider, which I placed at #34 instead of #29. The sentence then read `TGE ZOO WE VHSHTED TUESDAY REALLY PERTURBED ONLY ME LUKE AND JIM I FUESS ANYWAY WE CABBED GOME`, and it was easy to see how to move the divider to fix it.
>  [image: same image as above, but now three more dividers have been inserted, and all letters are filled in]

Comment: I assume in the last not quite right sentence that "LIKE" is a typo since it seems to be a long way from the correct word?

Comment: @Chris Ah, yep - that was a typo in my transcription from the image. Fixed, thank you!

Comment: Beautifully solved and beautifully explicated!

Answer (score 3):

Deusovi got it with 1 letter typo

Working out the number ranges following the Bee sting

> Letter ranges (working backwards through the numbers to find the beginning of each range)
>
> 1-6 7-9 10 11-15 16-28 29 30-31 32-35 36 37 38-41
>
> 42-44 45-47 48-51 52 53-55 56-59 60-63 64-67 68
>
> 69-71 72-76 77
>
> 23/26 letters

Slowly match letters to ranges

> 1-6 7-9 10 11-15 16-28 29 30-31
>
> *a  b  c   d     e    g  h*
>
> d  e  f   g     h    i  j
>
> 32-35 36 37 38-41 42-44 45-47
>
> i     j  k l     m     n
>
> k   l  m  n     o     p
>
> 48-51 52 53-55 56-59 60-63 64-67
>
> *o     p  r     s     t     u
>
> q    r    s   t     u     v
>
> 68 69-71 72-76 77
>
> *v  w     y     z
>
> w   x     y    z

Solution

> The zoo we visited Tuesday really perturbed only me, Luke, and Jim, I guess; anyway, we cabbed home.

I liked it.

Comment: I'm curious how you got to those letter ranges? ie why does the first letter range omit a letter (and similarly a few other ranges have letters missing)... Also how did you match the letters? did you just guess until you got things that looked right or was there more method to it?

Comment: I started out assuming a to z from the start and z to a from the end.  Shifting them around as I added letters to the puzzle, like there probably won't be 3 q's once you start working it out.  Assuming it was english the 1-3 letter words were pretty confident starting points.

Comment: That first letter range was what I corrected to copied from my phone's notepad.  So it wasn't very nicely presented...